# Continuously change hue of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to have the image change Hue – from -180 through 180 - in, say, 20 seconds? If so then having that process/script repeat/loop indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods that you could try.  The most compatible would probably be SVG or canvas.  There are [libraries for manipulating SVG images](http://svgjs.dev/) with JavaScript, and there's lots of documentation on canvas [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

Though support is limited as of writing, in the future you'll be able to use the new [CSS `filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).  You can combine that with [CSS @keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) to create animation with very little JavaScript, which would be pretty awesome.  Specifically, you'll want to look at the `hue-rotate` function for `filter`.

Comment: An online example of CSS filter: http://jsbin.com/qukef/1/edit?html,css,output The browser support is limited to Webkit browsers and Firefox 35+ right now.

Comment: @HashemQolami Amazing! Am I blind or is this not working for no reason? http://jsbin.com/hecovesuwu/1/edit?html,css,output I just added an ID

Comment: @ViruZX It still is working for me, tested in Chrome 38.

Comment: @HashemQolami Sorry im slowly losing my mind, this link: http://jsbin.com/josavezifi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @ViruZX Yes there's a mistake with your CSS selector, you should remove the space in `img #demo` just like `img#demo` - [Example](http://jsbin.com/josavezifi/1/edit?html,css,output) :)